# How do I recommend activities based on the sentiment of a text?

Tags: python, pandas, recommendation-engine

I have gotten my text sentiment classifier from this GitHub [link](https://github.com/viritaromero/Detecting-Depression-in-Tweets?source=post_page-----3f3a32a4df60----------------------) and it uses this dataset to test and train:

[image: tweet dataset]

The messages labelled with 0s are positive and the others labelled with 1s have a negative sentiment.
For example, if I run the function like this after the training/testing:

```
pm = process_message('Hi hello depression and anxiety are the worst')
sc_bow.classify(pm)
```

It would return `True` as it contains negative sentiment.

My plan right now is to build a recommender system to recommend activities to the user depending on whether or not the texts have a positive or negative sentiment.

This is the head of the dataset I have developed right now:

[image]

It contains a list of activities and its own label (1s and 0s). With 1 being activities to recommend when the user is being negative and vice versa.

Since I'm really new to machine learning, can anyone give me some pointers on how to achieve this goal of mine?

The course I'm currently following is this [Udemy course](https://www.udemy.com/course/python-for-data-science-and-machine-learning-bootcamp/).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a dataframe to contain those responses when a regular dict mapping a "response class" (i.e. the classification result) to possible options will do:

```py
import random

responses = {
  True: ["Take a bath", "Something", "Else"],
  False: ["Something", "Else"],
}

# ...

pm = process_message('Hi hello depression and anxiety are the worst')
response_class = sc_bow.classify(pm)
response = random.choice(responses.get(response_class, []))
print(response)
```